# PowerQuery - search for multiple acronyms in the list

Tags: powerquery

I wonder if it is possible in Power BI M:
I have a list of acronyms: "AAA, BBB, XXXX, YYY..."
Source data table has a text field (description) and can mention one or more of those in a free text. Something like "Luctus a a quam **AAA** gravida cum a **YYY** elementum potenti a ultrices p".
I need to select all records that have one or more acronym and generate additional custom column that would list all occurrences in a particular record ("AAA, YYY...").
It is a few lines of code in Excel VBA but I need to do it in PowerQuery or Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("DYhBCsAgDMC+UnreJ3rfB0Q8lK4MQZ3Tdu9fySVJzni6mG/g4HXuQERwL/7qxSDeY6eUQJt2HRY9Hwup8b3ZqqIbJpYjo+k2LOUH", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, {{"ad", each _, type table [Column1=nullable text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each let x = [ad],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(x, "Custom", each {"AAA", "BBB", "XXXX", "YYY"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "Custom.1", each Text.Contains([Column1],[Custom])),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", each ([Custom.1] = true)),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows", {"Column1"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Removed Duplicates",{"Custom", "Custom.1"}),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", each #"Filtered Rows"[Custom]),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom2", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    Custom = #"Extracted Values"[Custom]
in
    Custom),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"ad"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each (List.IsEmpty([Custom])=false)),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Filtered Rows", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From)), type text})
in
    #"Extracted Values"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, it's only two lines of Power Query code:

- Create a List of the relevant acronyms
- Match the contents of the string to the relevant acronym list items, and combine them with a delimiter:

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("FYw5DsAgDAS/sqLOJ6DOBxCisIgVEQE5sPP+ONpmZopNya1aRCfIdit1eO+xP/TWjVC0W44xght3HmJ+nWJQrWuTpxaeuFxekqOxN0YIAYxDp+j4v1zOHw==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),

acronyms = {"AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE","YYY"},

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", 
        each Text.Combine(
                List.Select(
                    Text.Split([Column1]," "), 
                        each List.Contains(acronyms,_)),", "), Text.Type)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is the idea, many thanks for the response.
How the code would change if both are tables imported from Excel?
Also I see you are splitting the source string into an array by spaces. This is not always working in my case.  Some times people write it like this: AAA/XXX, YYYY-AAA, so i need "contains" search through entire striing.

Comment: @GregoryDvorkin To split on any of multiple delimiters, you will want to use the `Text.SplitAny` function.

Comment: @GregoryDvorkin And you can easily make a list from an Excel table column. Read in the Table using the `Source2=Excel.Workbook)()...` function, then just refer to the column eg `acro=Source2[Column1]`